# Pad f-string with an open curly bracket char

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

In Python we can pad an f-string in this way:

```
>>> f"{' hello ':#^80}"
'#################################### hello #####################################'
```

How can I pad the `' hello '` string with the `{` character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an escape sequence for the brace itself:

```
>>> f"{' hello ':\x7b^80}"
'{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{ hello {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this way:

```
f"{' hello ':{chr(123)}^80}"
```

To determine the value as 123 of "{", you can run `ord("{")` which returns 123

**Output**:

```
'{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{ hello {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{'
```